# Microsoft Access Query Top 50% and Last 50% Values

Tags: sql, excel, ms-access

I have a Microsoft Access Query that has about 1.4m lines and need to export them to Microsoft Excel. As such, I thought of splitting it to the top 50% values in one sheet and the last 50% values in another sheet.

Using design view, under the Property Sheet of the query, I can select 50% under the Top Values field, but and have successfully exported that. But I have no idea how I can export the other half?

P/s: I don't have a unique primary key for the query, as it is a union of a left and right query (full join, or whatever name that might be), so I don't think I can use that to split the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the exact number of lines you want you could do something like this, although I am not too sure as to how efficient it will be with 1.4m lines.

```
select * 
from TABLE
where TABLEID not in (
    select top (
        (select count(*) from TABLE) - 700000
    ) TABLEID
    from TABLE
)
```

Or could you not use NOT IN or NOT EXISTS with your current query that you used to find the first 50%? [NOT IN vs. NOT EXISTS vs. LEFT JOIN](http://explainextended.com/2009/09/15/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-sql-server/)